# Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function cvGetMat in python opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to code in python opencv-2.4.3, It is giving me an error as below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/OpenCV-2.4.3/cam_try.py", line 6, in <module>
cv2.imshow('video test',im)
 error: /home/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/core/src/array.cpp:2482: error: (-206)           Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function cvGetMat
```

I am not understanding what does that mean, Can anybody help me out?
Thankyou.

Comment: Does the error immediately after you start the webcam program? Or does it occur after a few frames have been successfully returned?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relevant snippet of the error message is `Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function cvGetMat`. The `cvGetMat()` function converts arrays into a `Mat`. A `Mat` is the matrix data type that OpenCV uses in the world of C/C++ (Note: the Python OpenCV interface you are utilizing uses Numpy arrays, which are then converted behind the scenes into `Mat` arrays). With that background in mind, the problem appears to be that that the array `im` you're passing to `cv2.imshow()` is poorly formed. Two ideas:

1. This could be caused by quirky behavior on your webcam... on some cameras null frames are returned from time to time. Before you pass the `im` array to `imshow()`, try ensuring that it is not null.
2. If the error occurs on *every* frame, then eliminate some of the processing that you are doing and call `cv2.imshow()` immediately after you grab the frame from the webcam. If that still doesn't work, then you'll know it's a problem with your webcam. Else, add back your processing line by line until you isolate the problem. For example, start with this:

   ```
   while True:
       # Grab frame from webcam
       retVal, image = capture.read(); # note: ignore retVal

   #   faces = cascade.detectMultiScale(image, scaleFactor=1.2, minNeighbors=2, minSize=(100,100),flags=cv.CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING);

       # Draw rectangles on image, and then show it
   #   for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
   #       cv2.rectangle(image, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), 255)
       cv2.imshow("Video", image)

       i += 1;
   ```

source: [Related Question: OpenCV C++ Video Capture does not seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940780/opencv-c-video-capture-does-not-seem-to-work)

Comment: Thanks A lot, I was eagerly waiting for your reply.Yes it have some problem in cv2.imshow.And when i try to print image, it is None.IS it the problem of webcam? But it works fine for my simple video capture code of old version. When i try individually printing, it shows >>> capture
<VideoCapture 0x2c949d0>
>>> cascade
>>> print image  <None>. What should I Do??

Comment: where are you printing the image? If it is None right after capture.read(), then check the retVal variable which may contain an error code. Else tell me where you're printing it.

Comment: I am using python Idle as editor and when i print it gives as none and retVal as False.

Comment: If you are printing retVal and image right after you call `capture.read()`, then it sounds like you have a problem with your webcam. The documentation says retVal is False when "no frames have been grabbed (such as when a camera has been disconnected, or there are no more frames in video file)." Does your camera work in other cv2 v2.4.3 scripts?

Comment: I have reinstalled ubuntu 11.10 on my desktop and installing opencv-2.4.3, And want to restart again so that I will sure that  am not missing any opencv library. Is it a right decision to install opencv-2.4.3, I am new to processing, sorry for silly questions but you are using 2.4.3 so just want to ask, does it cause any problem while installing and processimg?

Comment: 2.4.3 is the latest stable release, so yes you should go ahead and use that version. I use a macbook so I'm not really sure how to install it on ubuntu. In general though, I'd forget about face detection at first and just try and view your raw webcam stream via opencv.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same error, and after about an hour of searching for the error, I found the path to the image to be improperly defined. It solved my problem, may be it will solve yours.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the porblem by using a BGR-picture. the one from my cam was YUYV by default!

Answer (score 0):

I am working in Windows with Opencv 2.3.1 and Python 2.7.2, so, I had the same problem, I solved it pasting the following DLL files: opencv_ffmpeg.dll and opencv_ffmpeg_64.dll in the installation folder of Python. Maybe it help you with a similar solution in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

For me, like Gab Hum did, I copied opencv_ffmpeg245.dll to my python code folder. Then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Image Array (or NpArray),(by printing it) whether you are trying to pass an array of images at one shot instead of passing each image at once.

A single image array would look like :

> [[[ 76  85 103] ... [ 76  85 103]], ... ]

Rows encloses each columns, each matrix(pixes) encloses no of rows, each image comprises of matrices (pixels).

Answer (score 0):

It is always good to have a sanity check, to be sure your camera is working.
In my case my camera is

raspistill -o test.jpg