# OpenCV Python unsupported array type error

Tags: python, opencv

I am new to Python (but not new to openCV) and I am pretty sure everything is installed correctly, I have tested some programs and the seem to work fine, but when ever I want to draw on an image, for example this code taken from a Python openCV tutorial :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
# Create a black image
img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)
# Draw a diagonal blue line with thickness of 5 px
img = cv2.line(img,(0,0),(511,511),(255,0,0),5)
cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I get this following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupported array type) in cvGetMat, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/core/src/array.cpp, line 2482
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/dccv/rec 2.py", line 17, in <module>
cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.error: /build/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/core/src/array.cpp:2482: error: (-206)
Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function cvGetMat
```

any help would be appreciated, I get the same error on both windows and ubuntu.

Comment: If I were to read and display an image without adding anything to it, it would work fine!

Comment: Is the path right? Is this relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155081/unrecognized-or-unsupported-array-type-in-function-cvgetmat-in-python-opencv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`line` function returns `None` so you're trying to show `None`.

The fix (on line 6) is to not set the `img` variable to the return value, instead just ignore the return value:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
# Create a black image
img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)
# Draw a diagonal blue line with thickness of 5 px
cv2.line(img,(0,0),(511,511),(255,0,0),5)
cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: @user3140249, your code is based on upcoming OpenCV 3.x version. But you have installed OpenCV 2.x. In OpenCV 3.x, all drawing functions like cv2.line() return an image, while not in OpenCV 2.x. So if you are referring to tutorials here (https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), please keep in mind those tutorials are for OpenCV 3.x